# Can call price increase in falling markets

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, volatility-smile

Say SPX falls so much that there is panic and implied volatility(iv) increases so greatly that OTM call prices are increased during the fall due to high iv

In my observation in historical data this doesn’t happens, call prices stops falling and stays constant as dip continues

Can anyone explain why this doesn’t happens?

Comment: This question (or comment?) looks to be more suitable for the Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange forum.

Comment: @Alper modified:)

Comment: For a first approximation, you can compare the option‘s Delta and Vega and imply a possible scenario.